# Add fields to the articles retrieved by ArticlesModel

Tags: articles, model

In my module i get the articles via this way:

```
$model = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Articles', 'ContentModel', array('ignore_request' => true));
$model->setState('params', JFactory::getApplication()->getParams());
$model->setState('filter.category_id', 22);
```

This gets all the articles from a specific category. But now I have the issue that the Fields from the com_fields component are not retrieved via this method. I probably have to do that myself. Does anyone know how to add the fields?

Something like

```
$model->addFields();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally fields are added by the Fields plugin. You can trigger `onContentPrepare` event to run this and other content plugins:

```
JFactory::getApplication()->triggerEvent('onContentPrepare', ['com_content.article', &$article, &$article->params]);
```

Fields will be available via `jcfields` property on the article object.

Another option is to manually use `FieldsHelper` class:

```
JLoader::register('FieldsHelper', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_fields/helpers/fields.php');
$fields = FieldsHelper::getFields('com_content.article', $article);
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you